# Automatic deployment of Azure website via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, msbuild

I'm busy writing some deployment scripts. One of the things this script needs to do is publish a new Azure Website.
To do so, I've already written some lines which create a new Website in Azure. Afterwards, my website has to be deployed. Reading up on this matter it appears this can be done using `msbuild` and the `DeployOnBuild` parameter.

So far the script looks like a bit like this (simplified):

```
New-AzureResourceGroup -Location $locationWestEUDataCenter -Name $resourceGroupNameEU
New-AzureResource -ApiVersion 2014-04-01 -Name $hostingPlanNameEU -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameEU `
                        -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/serverFarms -Location $locationWestEUDataCenter `
                        -PropertyObject $hostingPlanParametersEU -Verbose -Force
$siteWestEUProperties = @{name = $siteNameEU; sku = "Basic"; webHostingPlan = $hostingPlanNameEU}
New-AzureResource  -Name $siteNameEU -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites `
                         -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupNameEU -Location $locationWestEUDataCenter `
                         -ApiVersion $apiVersion -PropertyObject $siteWestEUProperties
Switch-AzureMode AzureServiceManagement
```

The MSBuild publish looks like this at the moment (copy of http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/automate-everything):

```
& "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" $websiteProjectFileAnalytics `
    /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 `
    /p:DeployOnBuild=true `
    /p:PublishProfile=$publishingFileAnalytics `
    /p:Password=$publishSettings.publishData.publishProfile.userPWD.get(0)
```

The problem I'm having with this line of code is the `Password` property. The password has to be retrieved from a PublishSettings file. This passwork isn't present on the subscription PublishSettings file. This password (and a lot of other properties) is present in the PublishSettings file which you can download from the website management page in the Azure portal.

See my problem here?

I want a fully automated deployment of the complete software suite. Is there a way I can set the password of the specific websites I'm creating? If this is possible, I can manage the password in PowerShell and use the password while publishing.

Or is there a different/better way to automate the deployments of Azure Websites?

On a sidenote: I'm a PowerShell newbie, but already succeeded in automatically deploying Cloud Services, Service Busses, database, Traffic Manager, Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's always the same, after asking a question you read something which might be the solution of your problem.*

In a [blog post of Kaushal Kumar Panday](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/29/windows-azure-web-sites-reset-deployment-credentials-v-s-reset-publish-profile-credentials.aspx) was reading the following:

> Now lets click on the option “Reset your deployment credentials”. This
> will prompt the user with the following pop-up:
>
> image
>
> Now, this option is self explanatory. It allows the user to change the
> deployment credentials i.e., the username and password. However this
> option is **not specific to a website**, as the user is changing the
> password for the deployment account, it will affect all the web sites.
> These credentials are directly tied to the Microsoft account
> (Outlook.com or Live.com). So **changing these credentials** will be
> changing it for **all the subscriptions** tied to the Microsoft account.

This means I can change the deployment credentials once, for the subscription, and use these credentials in my script. Doing so results in the following command:

```
& "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" $websiteProjectFileAnalytics `
    /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 `
    /p:DeployOnBuild=true `
    /p:PublishProfile=$publishingFileAnalytics `
    /p:Password=$azureDeploymentPassword `
    /p:UserName=$azureDeploymentUsername `
    /p:MSDeployServiceURL=mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net:443
```

For this to work, you do need to remove the `UserName` and `MSDeployServiceURL` elements from your pubxml file. I also removed the `_SavePWD` element as it doesn't do anything anymore (I guess).

My website is now successfully deployed to Azure.